# If we have events $E_k, k \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $P(E_k) = 0$ for all $k \in \mathbb{R}$, what is $P(\cup_{k \in \mathbb{R}}E_k)$ equal to?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Here, we have an uncountably many number of sets. In this case, we cannot use Boole's inequality to show it is equal to 0 as in the countable case, but I am not sure whether and what the value is. Can anyone show me a hint? thanks!

Comment: Could be anything from $0$ to $1$.

Comment: Or even undefined.

Comment: Not everyone agrees with inclusion of the countable additivity axiom either, so even in the countable case the answer depends on inclusion of countable additivity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer need not be zero. Example: If $P$ is Lebesgue measure restricted to the unit interval, and $E_k=\left\{ k\right\}$ is a single point for every $k\in\mathbb R$, then $P(E_k)=0$ for all $k$ but the union of the $E_k$'s has probability $1$.

Comment: Or as sangchul pointed, the question may even be meaningless